# Angular 6 Unable to map response to Observable?

Tags: angular, observable

I'm new to Angular and I am trying to create a simple POC.

I created a service that invokes OpenWeatherMap API

```
export class WeatherService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  fetchWeather(): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=xxx&q=london&units=metric')
  }
}
```

The response JSON looks like

```
/ 20190327154650
// http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=xxx&q=london&units=metric

{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0.0082,
  "cnt": 40,
  "list": [{event1},{event2}...]
}
```

I assign the response to 'weather':

```
this.weather = fetchWeather();
```

and then try to iterate with:

```
<li *ngFor="let event of weather.list | async">{{ event }}</li>
```

but nothing gets printed.

If I mock the response to be just

```
[{event1},{event2}...]
```

then it works using

```
<li *ngFor="let event of weather | async">{{ event }}</li>
```

The first issue I noticed is that the response starts with a comment.
Second, I can't seem to be able to access properties of 'weather' (e.g. 'weather.cod').

How do I work with the original response from the API?

Comment: show the code where you assign the variable.  Both of these don't work for valid reasons, but i need to see how you're assigning it to fix it.

Comment: Seems like the problem is `*ngFor` expects an array, but the API is returning an object.

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of what would work (if using the async pipe)

in component.ts:

```
this.weather = this.weatherService.fetchWeather().pipe(map(weather => weather.list));
```

then in template:

```
<li *ngFor="let event of weather | async">{{ event }}</li>
```

the async pipe requires an observable input and ngFor requires an iterable, so you solve this with the map operator.

Just a note, be careful if you're using a http backed observable with the async pipe.  It can yield an unnecessary or unexpected number of http calls if you use more than one async pipe which has performance concerns.

Comment: I tried already with the pipe but it didn't make any difference